# TripleDES encryption not getting same value in PHP as in VB

Tags: php, vb.net, tripledes

I found a lot of solutions that explain how to look at C# versus PHP, but none specific to VB.  I did find one helpful hint about PHP padding with zeroes, but that didn't solve the problem as I matched that in VB and it didn't help.  Anyway I am familiar with VB and we have another developer familiar with PHP and we are trying to make our functions match so that tripleDES encryption spits out the same value in both.  We are integrating with a third party application, and I know the VB code is spitting out the correct value but PHP is not.  I have both VB and PHP code listed below, would anyone out there be familiar enough with both to have any idea why the PHP code isn't returning the correct value?  I know the value that is being returned from PHP is the correct length, but there is something off and it's not matching.  Please help.

VB:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim dataToHash As String
    Dim encryptedText As String = ""

    dataToHash = "hereismystring"
    Dim buffer As Byte() = Encryption(dataToHash, "abcd1234")
    encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)

    lblToken.Text = encryptedText.ToString()
End Sub

Public Shared Function Encryption(ByVal PlainText As String, ByVal key As String) As Byte()
    Dim des As TripleDES = CreateDES(key)
    Dim ct As ICryptoTransform = des.CreateEncryptor()
    Dim input As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(PlainText)
    Return ct.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length)
End Function

Private Shared Function CreateDES(ByVal key As String) As TripleDES
    Dim md5 As MD5 = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim des As TripleDES = New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()
    des.Key = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key))
    des.IV = New Byte(des.BlockSize / 8 - 1) {}
    des.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros
    Return des
End Function
```

PHP:

```
$start = "hereismystring";

$cipher = MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES;
$mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;

$rawKey = "abcd1234";
$ssoKey = md5($key_encoded,true);

$key_size = strlen($ssoKey);
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$ssoIV = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

$user_str = mb_convert_encoding($start,"UTF-16LE");    

$key_blocksize = mcrypt_get_block_size($cipher,$mode);
$key_padding_size = $key_blocksize - (strlen($user_str) % $key_blocksize);

$user_str .= str_repeat(chr($key_padding_size), $key_padding_size);
$key_iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($cipher,$mode),"");
$key_triple = substr($key_encoded,0,mcrypt_get_key_size($cipher,$mode));

$key_encoded_text = mcrypt_encrypt($cipher,$key_triple,$user_str,$mode,$key_iv);

$final = base64_encode($key2_encoded_text);

echo "<p>" . $final </p>";     
?>
```

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: VB.NET compiles to the same thing as C#, so the discussion should be the same. What resources did you find comparing C# to PHP?

Comment: Hi, yes I understand that.  I was basically saying I couldn't find anything that helped me.  There were about 3 or 4 stackoverflow threads I read through and none were helpful.